# Can't understand the working of this C program?

Tags: c, gcc

I am trying to understand why this code is not doing what I expect it to.

When I run it I get 1 (or as mentioned in comments below, at most 2) even when entering only b.  My expectation is that it should continue to loop until I enter a character other than b.

I'm not yet very well versed in `C`.  Can anyone explain to me how this can be changed so it works as expected?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void run()
{
    int counter=0;
    char a='b';
    while(a=='b')
    {
        counter++;
        scanf("%c",&a);
    }
    printf("%d",counter);
}
int main()
{
    run();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What did you expect?  variable `a` is initialized to `b` thus `while` condition is always true for the first time making your `counter` `1`.

Comment: with an input starting with a numbers of b's you should get a result > 1

Comment: Try entering a single line with multiple 'b' characters in front and you'll get some other (count of 'b's + 1) result.

Comment: @kiranBiradar if i provide a as an input, it gives 1 which is understood. If i give b as an input, it gives 2 as an output. But if i give b b b b b b as an input, it still gives 2. That is what i cant understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From comments:  *But if i give b b b b b b as an input, it still gives 2*

Change the statement:

```
   scanf("%c",&a);
```

To:

```
scanf(" %c",&a);
       ^
```

The space in front of the format specifier `%c` will consume any white space character (or even a series of *[characters considered white space](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_isspace.htm)* in `C` ) seen in the input before the intended character is read, in this example allowing the value finally scanned in to be precisely `b`, and not `\n`, or   (space) which was causing the loop to exit.

Answer (score 0):

> But if I give `b b b b b b` as an input, it still gives 2. That is what
>   I can't understand.

It is because you have designed your program that way, you are always expecting `b` to inputted and your input contains mix of `b` and space.

Try as below.

```
 void run()
 {
     int counter=0;
     char a='b';
     while(scanf("%c", &a) > 0 && a != '\n')
     {   
        if (a == 'b')
         counter++;
     }   
     printf(" %d",counter);
 }

 int main()
 {
     run();
    return 0;
 }
```